# Iintegrate Spring Security into spring mvc 3.2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a SpringMVC 3.2 app that I would like to add Spring Security to.  I have read some tutorials and downloaded examples.  The problem I am running into is that my app uses JavaConfig and all the Spring Security examples use web.xml, which I don't have.  I looked at the spring-security-javaconfig project, but I haven't found the best way to actually implement it.  I can create a @Configuration class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but I can't say I fully understand how it works.  I know that I'll want custom roles, ip restrictions, and remember-me.  But is it really so simple that I just need the one @Configuration class?

Does anyone have any resources to help on integrating these two projects?  Or is it better to just stick with Spring Security via XMl and find a way to marry those two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with `spring-security-javaconfig` is that it is not yet released.

In one of our application we have configured security in `@Configuration` manually. But I know a thing or two about Spring's security inner workings so that was quite easy for me. I can imagine it might not be so easy for a non-experienced user.

I would suggest you to configure security via XML. It is easier, well documented and it just works.

You can import security XML configuration via `@ImportResource` from your `@Configuration` class. Registering `DelegatingFilterProxy` with a correct name *springSecurityFilterChain* from you `WebApplicationInitializer` should be also piece of cake.

Comment: Thank you Pavel, I am taking your approach and its nearly right.